# How should one create a dataset using the tensorflow.data.Dataset api from a large set of wav files?

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, wav, tensorflow-datasets

I have 8,742 wav files (amounting to around 7.1GB) and would like to get the raw data into a `tf.data.Dataset`.

My first attempt is below. Please note that I used the `soundfile` package as the wav files have different bit rates and some are 24bit per sample. It is my understanding that many packages do not offer support for 24bit wav files.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import soundfile

filepaths = tf.gfile.Glob('michael/dataset/wav_filepaths/*.wav') #Get the files into a list

labels = get_labels #pseudo function to obtain corresponding labels to audio

raw_audio = [] #List to hold raw audio lists. These are 2 channel wavs so this will be a 3D list

#Create a list were each element is raw audio data
for f in filepaths:
    try:
        data, sample_rate = soundfile.read(f) #2 channels
        raw_audio.append(data.tolist())
    except Exception as err: #Poor practice to catch all exceptions like this but it is just an example
        print ('Exception')
        print (f)

training_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((raw_audio, labels))
```

The problem with this solution is that it is horrendously slow as soundfile reads all of the raw data and stores it all in a list.

I am now considering a solution whereby I initially store filenames and corresponding labels in a `tf.data.Dataset`. I would then create a mapping function which calls `soundfile.read` or possibly even use `tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.audio_ops` within the function and only return the raw audio and corresponding label. The function would be called using the `tf.data.Dataset.map` function so that the whole process becomes part of the graph and is parallelised.

My first concern with the proposed solution is that it is not ideal and seems a bit "hacky" to store filenames in a dataset to later be replaced by corresponding data. My second concern is that the GPU I am using (1080Ti with 11GB memory) could run out of memory.

Please provide a better way (in particular it should be faster) to get raw audio data from a large set of wav files into a `tf.data.Dataset`.

Comment: Does every sound file have the same exact number of samples? Otherwise I suppose you would need to add padding if you want to have multiple wav files in one batch? Apparently there is [`tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/ffmpeg/decode_audio), but in general the easiest route for these cases is to [convert the data to TFRecord format](http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html) first and then [consume that with the dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_tfrecord_data).

Comment: Hmm I think they are all stereo, so same number of samples but different number of frames. So I will be sure to pad them, thanks :).

I would ideally prefer to avoid the tfrecord option if possible. I would like the network to train and infer on raw data ideally. As I would have to provide a tensor to any tf function anyway (including 'tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio') should I create a dataset with the filenames and use a mapping function?

Comment: Well with TFRecords you would train on raw data, it's just a file format were you would put the decoded WAV file directly. Anyway, yes to use [tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/ffmpeg/decode_audio) you would have to give the list of files (or use [`tf.data.Dataset.list_files`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files)) and map them with [`tf.read_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/read_file) and that function.

Comment: @jdehesa although it wasn't the solution that I wanted, it does seem that using tfrecords is the "tensorflowy" (acceptable tensorflow equivalent to "pythonic" :P?) way to deal with data that is too large to fit in memory. It seems that the issue I was having was with memory, rather than the speed speed of soundfile.read. So this is an acceptable solution. If you write this into an answer then I am happy to accept it. Thanks, Michael.

Comment: @jdehesa Out of curiosity, do people ever use a filename queue or something similar to read data into a tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: Are you referring to the TensorFlow queues that were used for multithreading (the ones discussed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues))? I never actually used them, and I haven't seen them used in combination with datasets (but maybe someone does). In principle the idea is that the `tf.data` API should cover all their use cases.

Comment: Yes those are the ones that I am referring to. I was just wondering if it would allow me to skirt the problem of lack of memory prior to putting it into a dataset. Although I realise that that would be rather "hacky".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could in theory read the files with [`tf.read_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/read_file) and decode them with [`tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/ffmpeg/decode_audio), the usual approach for this kind of cases is to convert the data to TFRecord format and read it with a [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset). [This blog post](http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html) shows an example of how to do that, in your case you would need a script that reads each WAV file, decodes it and writes the vector of samples (I suppose as a 32-bit value would be the simplest way) in the file. Note that if you want to batch multiple audio files into a tensor either they must have all the same size or you would have to use [`tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) to form proper tensors.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a generator function which feeds the data into the pipline. Take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator

Comment: This works beautifully, I think most people use the tfRecord solution given to me above. But the tf.data.Dataset api is still quite new I guess. Thanks for your answer, Michael.

Comment: Np.  By the way. Depending on your use case you can even write your own tf data reader. https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/new_data_formats the Documentation is quite hidden :)